# Payment module in Kohana 3?

Tags: kohana

I've been using Kohana 2.3.7. There are somethings that are holding us back to using Kohana 3 and one is the lack of modules compared to 2.3.7. For instance, I can't seem to find the Payment module (Paypal, 2C0, Authorize.net, etc) present in 2.3 to 3. If there is already, can you please direct me to it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the official authorize.net PHP SDK as a Kohana module.

http://dev.strategystar.net/2011/10/authorize-net-module-for-kohana-3-x/

I hope it helps. The two resources that Pixel Developer posted work nicely for Paypal and Google Checkout.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few payment modules for Kohana 3.

1. [Paypal](http://github.com/shadowhand/paypal)
2. [Google Checkout](http://github.com/shadowhand/gcheckout)

Both created by Woody Gilk.

You also have the option of porting the Kohana 2 libraries. Takes no longer than half a day and gets the job done.